# What happens if I kill a butterfly?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I was trying to capture a butterfly in *Skyward Sword*, when I accidentally hit B and put the bug net away.  Unknowingly, I continued to swing.  This armed my sword, and **before I realized it, I had killed the poor butterfly I was trying to capture.**

I had a similar incident early in the game, before I bought the bug net: I tried using the beetle to capture a grasshopper.  To my horror (and probably the grasshoppers), the beetle killed it.

**Does killing an insect effect the game at all?**  Or are there enough bugs to go around?

Comment: You're a monster.

Comment: You're killing them just to watch their tiny insect death animation aren't you?

Comment: Username is strangely appropriate.

Comment: Also, this needs the [murder] tag. :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bugs respawn like grass and monsters. There's no harm in killing them other than needing to leave the area and come back to capture them.

<sub>(Plus the long-lasting and appropriate stain on your conscience. You *murdered* a *butterfly*.)</sub>

Comment: Cold blooded murder....